# Querying table data in angular fails with error "cannot read properties of null"

Tags: angular, html-table, jasmine

I am trying to write a unit test in Angular to check if a table renders expected data.
This is my sample HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr id="columnTitle">
      <td id="color">Color</td>
      <td>Quantity</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Red</td>
      <td>100</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

To check if the table contains cells containing the text "Color", I tried querying the cells with an id:

```
const color = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#color'); // line A
expect(color); // works
expect(color.textContent).toContain('Color'); // fails (cannot find property textContent of null)
```

While the first test passed, indicating that the element exists, the second failed with the error "Cannot read properties of null", implying that no element with the given id was found. This seems to be a contradiction that I am unable to understand.

I have also tried modifying line A to the query below but that didn't work either:

```
const color = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#color'));
expect(color); // works
expect(color.nativeElement.textContent).toContain('Color'); // fails (cannot find nativeElement of null)
```

How do I work around this issue?

Comment: have you try to do a console.log of color. to see what kind of element or info you are getting?

Comment: I have but it doesn't print anything because this code is in the spec.ts file and not a part of the code that renders components

Comment: If you inspect the test page (the one where karma/ jazmine shows the outputs) you'll have the console print there. It's what I do when I can't find any solution or the console can't be place on the component. Also you can try this out with the fixture.detectChanges https://www.concretepage.com/angular/angular-test-html-element

Comment: Adding fixture.detectChanges() is giving me a "...is not a function error" in my actual code (what I posted above is a simple example). Also, I looked in Inspect > console on the karma debugger page but I do not see the console.log statements that I added in the spec file:(

Answer (score 0):

querySelector design to deal with css class but it work with identifier, try
this:
Change

```
const color = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#color');
```

To

```
const color = document.querySelector('#color');
```

Comment: This is still giving me the same propertied of null error when I try to access the textContent element of color:(

Comment: I checked in my env and it worked, which angular version you're using?